# implement an in-game currency

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, persistence, currency

I currently have a half-made Swift/SpriteKit game, and I'd like to add some sort of in-game currency variable that will always retain its value, even after closing the app itself. How would I add such a thing?

Comment: That is not related to sprite kit or apple at all. And only tangentially to iOS or swift (and currency as a concept). You are asking more about persistence of data.

Comment: You should look into Core Data, SQLite, or implementing the `NSCoding` protocol, any of which will give you data persistence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to save it you can do like this:

```
func saveCurrency(value:Double){
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(value, forKey: "currency")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

to load it:

```
func loadCurrency()-> Double{
    return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("currency")
}
```

to delete/reset the value:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("currency")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

usage:

```
saveCurrency(123.0)
println(loadCurrency())   // 123.0
```

Comment: Would this be in the AppDelegate?

Comment: I usually put my functions on a swift source file called Main.swift